# How to split a string in C++, containing two integers delimited by ":"?

Tags: c++, string

I have a string like this:

```
string str = "18:10";
```

18 is the minutes and 10 is the seconds.

I need to split the string `str` and store them into two int variables.

So essentially like this: `int a = 18`, `int b =10`. How do I do that?

Comment: [Check this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/6021126), then use std::stoi.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? It seems like you just want community to do the job for you.

Comment: Agreed with @MokonaModoki. YOu should try at least once.

Comment: I'm new with C++, I use python a lot, I just switched to C++. In python, I can just do str.split(":").

Comment: I don't see how this is a valid excuse.

Comment: i'm so sorry,of course I tried myself. I tried: string str = "18:10"; istringstream iss(str); int n; while(iss>n) { int a; int b; cin >> a >>b;}. And it did not work. lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How do I iterate over the words of a string?](/q/236129/90527)", "[How can I split a string by a delimiter into an array?](/q/890164/90527)", "[How do I tokenize a string in C++?](/q/53849/90527)", "[Is There A Built-In Way to Split Strings In C++?](/q/599989/90527)", "[How can I convert a std::string to int?](/q/7663709/90527)", "[convert string to int use sstream](/q/18931990/90527)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few way to do this, C style (`atoi`, `atof` etc). In C++ we'd use `std::stringstream` from the header `sstream`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
T convertString( std::string str ) {
    T ret;
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    ss >> ret;
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "18:10";
    int minutes,seconds;

    minutes = convertString<int>(str.substr(0,2));
    seconds = convertString<int>(str.substr(3,4));

    std::cout<<minutes<<" "<<seconds<<"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
18 10
```

This, of course, assumes that your string follow this format exactly (same number of integers, seperated by colon..). If you need to use this in a wider context, perhaps you'd be interested in using the `std::regex` utility instead.

Comment: I wonder why you have the template? Could this work for other types as well such as `float` and `double`?

Comment: @smttsp I believe so, looking at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/, _"Extracts and parses characters sequentially from the stream to interpret them as the representation of a value of the proper type, which is stored as the value of val...."_. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <class NumberType, class CharType>
NumberType StringToNumber(const std::basic_string<CharType> & String)
{
    std::basic_istringstream<CharType> Stream(String);
    NumberType Number;
    Stream >> Number;
    return Number;
}

const std::string str("18:10");
const size_t Pos = str.find(':');
const auto Hour = StringToNumber<int>(str.substr(0, Pos));
const auto Minute = StringToNumber<int>(str.substr(Pos + 1, std::string::npos));
```

I didn't test it. Fix it if there is any error. You have to do error handling if your string may have empty parts for hours or minutes (e.g.; ":10", "18:" or ":").

Comment: you don't have to worry about error handling, all strings have mins and secs

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "18:10";
string first_number, second_number;


int position =  str.find(':'); // remember thats it is counting from 0
for(int i = 0; i < position; i++){
   first_number = first_number + str[i];
}
cout << "first_number: " << first_number << endl;

for(int i = position+1; i < str.length(); i++){ // position+1 beacasue we dont wanna ':' in our string -> second_number
   second_number = second_number + str[i];
}
cout << "second_number: " << second_number << endl;
```