# Splitting C++ strings using a Delimiter

Tags: c++, date, struct, split, delimiter

Okay, So I've looked around on StackOverflow and I've stumbled across a way of splitting C++ via delimiters.

So far, I've looked at these, and I still don't understand it.

- [Parse (split) a string in C++ using string delimiter (standard C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c)
- https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-cookbook/0596007612/ch04s07.html
- [C++ spliting string by delimiters and keeping the delimiters in result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706443/c-spliting-string-by-delimiters-and-keeping-the-delimiters-in-result)
- [split a C++ string into two integers, which are delimited by ":"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810504/split-a-c-string-into-two-integers-which-are-delimited-by)

From my understanding, I need to use a delimiter, using a variable that houses the delimiter, and then use the `substr()` method/function, but I don't understand the whole thing.

For instance, I saw this one example where it was referencing `pos` and `npos`, I don't understand that. And my other issue is, I wouldn't know how to do it with a string with multiple copies of the same delimiter.

My goal is to take a date like this: `"29/01/2022 • 05:25:01"` to split it into a struct for date and time, eg:

```
struct Date
{
    int day;           //Integer for days
    int month;         //Integer for months
    int year;          //Integer for years
};

struct Time 
{
    int hour;           //Integer for hour of drop
    int minute;         //Integer for minute of drop
    int second;         //Integer for second of drop
    int milisecond;     //Integer for milisecond of drop
};
```

I've also looked at https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/, however I want to split it up so that they are stored in their own variables, eg:

```
string example
{
    struct Date D;
    struct Time T;

    D.Day = 29;
    D.Month = 01;
    D.Year = 2022;

    T.Hour = 5;
    T.Minute = 25;
    T.Second = 01;
}
```

Would someone be able to explain this to me in a simpler way, or show me a source that explains it easier? The main problem I have is not understanding certain words.

Any help is appreciated, I really am trying to learn, but I don't quite understand these subjects yet.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are asking - your question is about splitting a string by delimiters, but the code you've shown here doesn't even attempt that.   Moreover, your code with your `string example` doesn't even compile - are you trying to initialize `example` with your `Date D` and `Time T`?

Comment: have a look at [`std::get_time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time), which allows you to custom-parse date/time values from any `std::istream`. For instance, you can put your string into an `std::istringstream` and then parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go step by step, starting with the date:

```
29/01/2022  -- Day, Month, Year.
```

Given the following:

```
unsigned int day = 0u;
std::cin >> day;
```

The input of an integer skips whitespace until the first number character (for the first number character, also includes '+' and '-').  The extraction operator keeps reading characters, building a number, until a non-numeric character is reached:

2 --> day.
9 --> day.

The next character is '/', which is not a numeric character so the extraction operator returns the number `29`.

The character '/' in this context is known as a delimiter, because it separates the day field from the month field.
Since it's a character, it has to be read using a character variable:

```
char delimiter = '\0';  
std::cin >> delimiter;
```

Now, the delimiter is no longer in the buffer.
You can check the content of the delimiter variable or move on.

Reading the month is similar:

```
unsigned int month = 0U;
std::cin >> month;
```

**Edit 1: delimiter and substrings**
You could extract the month as a string using a delimiter:

```
std::string month_as_text;
std::getline(std::cin, month_as_text, '/');
```

The `getline` function above reads characters from `std::cin`, placing into the string `month_as_text`, until it finds the *delimiter* character `'/'`.  You can then convert `month_as_text` into an integer variable.

Comment: Could you please expand on this bit as I don't quite understand "The input of an integer skips whitespace until the first number character (for the first number character, also includes '+' and '-'). The extraction operator keeps reading characters, building a number until a non-numeric character is reached:

2 --> day. 9 --> day."